# Include values from other rows in output Postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with Infos about Objects for Rent. (Postgres v.10)

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=25aefcbf9a1cb3baa704fd9a5a0bb7ff)

```
id  start_date  end_date    objekt_id   person_id
1   2011-10-01  2015-10-31  5156        18268
2   2015-11-01  2018-04-30  5156        18268
3   2018-05-01  2021-03-31  5156        18269
4   2021-04-01  2021-05-15  5156    
5   2021-05-16  2100-01-01  5156        18270
6   2021-03-14  2100-01-01  5160        18270
```

Now i want to add the last id and the next id on the same row where the objekt_id and person_id is not null.

Wished output for Object 5156

```
    id  start_date  end_date    objekt_id   person_id   last_id   next_id
    1   2011-10-01  2015-10-31  5156        18268                 2
    2   2015-11-01  2018-04-30  5156        18268       1         3
    3   2018-05-01  2021-03-31  5156        18269       2         5 --here next is 5 since 4 has person_id null
    4   2021-04-01  2021-05-15  5156                            
    5   2021-05-16  2100-01-01  5156        18270       3         
    6   2021-03-14  2100-01-01  5160        18270
```

The goal in the end for me is to find out who rents something at a specific date and who rented it the last time and who is the next one to rent (if there is one).

I tried something like this but it doensn't work.

```
select r.id,r.start_date,r.end_date,r.objekt_id,r.person_id, rentlast.id
from rent r
inner join rent rentlast on rentlast.id = (select r3.id from rent r3 where r3.objekt_id = r.id and r3.person_id is not null and r3.id<r.id order by id desc limit 1 )
```

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use lag() / lead() function with PARTITION BY clause.
Something like this is the expected result?

```
with tbl as (
SELECT rent.*,
row_number() over (PARTITION BY objekt_id) as row_id
    FROM rent
    ORDER BY id)
SELECT r.id,
       r.start_date,
       r.end_date,
       r.objekt_id,
       r.person_id,
       lag(row_id) over (PARTITION BY objekt_id, person_id IS NOT NULL AND objekt_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id) as last_row,
       lead(row_id) over (PARTITION BY objekt_id, person_id IS NOT NULL AND objekt_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id) as next_row
    FROM tbl r
order by 1;
```

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQCZq.png)

Comment: Sound like a good idea with lag and lead. In your output ID 6 has last_row 5 witch isn't correct since id 5,6 has different object_id's.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed the code according to your new condition (added partitioning by objekt_id)